# Troubleshooting a deploy to heroku - RuntimeError: The reset parameter is False but there is no n_features_in_ attribute. Is this estimator fitted?

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, heroku, web-applications

Hi Stackeoverflow Community. I working on a simple project for a class involving hosting a flask app that allows users to input values and get a prediction of who is going to win. Well, in runs OK on our local machines using python flask, but is presenting challenges on heroku. Stumped!

The code is not lengthy or complicated. Also know that we have some opps as well.

our App.py file looks like:

```
import flask
import tensorflow
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from pickle import load
from load import *

model = init()

scaler = load(open('model/scaler.pkl', 'rb'))
print("Awesome, your scaler has been loaded from disk! Cool beans!")

app = flask.Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    global model 
    if flask.request.method == 'GET':
        return(flask.render_template('main.html'))
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        R_Weight = flask.request.form['R_Weight']
        R_Height = flask.request.form['R_Height']
        R_Age = flask.request.form['R_Age']
        B_Weight = flask.request.form['B_Weight']
        B_Height = flask.request.form['B_Height']
        B_Age = flask.request.form['B_Age']
        RPrev = 2.130049
        BPrev = 1.756650
        BStreak = 0.643350
        RStreak = 0.748768
        input_variables = pd.DataFrame([[BPrev, BStreak, B_Age,B_Height,B_Weight,RPrev, RStreak, R_Age,R_Height,R_Weight]],
                                    columns=['BPrev','BStreak','B_Age','B_Height','B_Weight','RPrev','RStreak','R_Age','R_Height','R_Weight'],
                                    dtype=float)
        input_scaled = scaler.transform(input_variables)
        prediction = model.predict(input_scaled)[0][0]
        if np.round(prediction) == 0:
            prediction = "Blue"
        else:
            prediction = "Red"   

        if int(R_Weight) < 20:
            prediction = "Invalid Weight"
        elif int(B_Weight) < 20:
            prediction = "Invalid Weight"
        elif int(R_Height) < 20:
            prediction = "Invalid Height"
        elif int(B_Height) < 20:
            prediction = "Invalid Height"
        elif int(R_Age) < 18:
            prediction = "Invalid Age"
        elif int(B_Age) < 18:
            prediction = "Invalid Age"

        return flask.render_template('main.html',
                                      original_input={'R_Weight' :R_Weight,
                                                    'R_Height' :R_Height,
                                                    'R_Age' :R_Age,
                                                    'B_Weight' :B_Weight,
                                                    'B_Height' :B_Height,
                                                    'B_Age' :B_Age
                                                     },
                                     result=prediction
                                     )

@app.route('/logisticregression')
def logreg():
    return(flask.render_template('00_model_logisticsregression.html'))

@app.route('/gridsearch')
def grisea():
    return(flask.render_template('00_model_gridsearch.html'))

@app.route('/deeplearning')
def deelea():
    return(flask.render_template('01_training_model.html'))

@app.route('/viz1')
def viz1():
    return(flask.render_template('00_data_visualization_a.html'))

@app.route('/viz2')
def viz2():
    return(flask.render_template('00_data_visualization_b.html'))

@app.route('/viz3')
def viz3():
    return(flask.render_template('00_data_visualization_c.html'))

@app.route('/trained')
def traine():
    return(flask.render_template('02_notraining_model.html'))

@app.route('/debugging')
def debugg():
    return(flask.render_template('03_debugger.html'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The error I see in heroku is:

```
2020-05-31T19:43:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-31T19:48:29.426002+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.81.161.51 - - [31/May/2020:19:48:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4710 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
2020-05-31T19:48:29.432446+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bcs-final.herokuapp.com request_id=1df55828-886a-45d1-9605-aafd3414f9e3 fwd="71.143.151.112" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=56ms status=200 bytes=4872 protocol=https
2020-05-31T19:48:29.623294+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.81.161.51 - - [31/May/2020:19:48:29 +0000] "GET /reset.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://bcs-final.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
2020-05-31T19:48:29.623792+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/reset.css" host=bcs-final.herokuapp.com request_id=40816718-e41b-44e9-a3d5-da5ff2030adb fwd="71.143.151.112" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
2020-05-31T19:48:29.625560+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.244.15 - - [31/May/2020:19:48:29 +0000] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://bcs-final.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
2020-05-31T19:48:29.627392+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/style.css" host=bcs-final.herokuapp.com request_id=bd01a28c-7d1e-4dc6-9a85-405b1bdbb8ea fwd="71.143.151.112" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727173+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-31 19:48:37,723] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727185+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727186+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727186+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727187+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727215+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727216+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727217+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727218+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727218+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727219+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727219+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727220+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727220+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727221+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 36, in main
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727221+00:00 app[web.1]: input_scaled = scaler.transform(input_variables)
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727222+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py", line 794, in transform
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727222+00:00 app[web.1]: force_all_finite='allow-nan')
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727222+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 436, in _validate_data
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727223+00:00 app[web.1]: self._check_n_features(X, reset=reset)
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727223+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 373, in _check_n_features
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727223+00:00 app[web.1]: "The reset parameter is False but there is no "
2020-05-31T19:48:37.727314+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError: The reset parameter is False but there is no n_features_in_ attribute. Is this estimator fitted?
2020-05-31T19:48:37.728944+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.244.15 - - [31/May/2020:19:48:37 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://bcs-final.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
2020-05-31T19:48:37.730539+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=bcs-final.herokuapp.com request_id=2ba8ae51-f913-48d0-9b45-78aef407c15e fwd="71.143.151.112" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=470 protocol=https
```

Comment: Can you share which version of scikit-learn you are using?

Comment: I am getting the same error when restoring a fitted model and trying to transform. The model is definitely fitted. It works for sklearn v.0.22.0 but not for 0.23.0; a rollback did the trick for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code I can not say for sure what is the difference between running your app locally vs on heroku. The only sane guess would be that your local env has different version of the lib than the one that is run on heroku.

Anyhow, if we focus on what heroku's version is telling us, your error is coming from this line:

```
# ...
input_scaled = scaler.transform(input_variables) # <--- here
# ...
```

The error basically says: the estimator - which is actually your scaler (see the source code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/337a2f00ed97322fd74ecb2e7c97aa1ccac6c7bb/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py#L811)) - is not fitted.

The message itself is printed out [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/337a2f00ed97322fd74ecb2e7c97aa1ccac6c7bb/sklearn/base.py#L368) and the part saying "`n_features_in_` attribute missing" essentially means that your `input_variables` sparse matrix (in scikit-learn source code referred as `X`) is missing the attribute `n_features_in_`. That attribute is set  as part of the fitting process.

Bottom line, invoke `fit` before `transform` and that might help. So something like:

```
input_scaled = scaler.fit(input_variables).transform(input_variables)
```

Comment: I do not believe this method works as intended. The OP wants to load a transformer that has already been fit previously. If you call .fit().transform() again, you are creating a new transformer which is not the correct method. Any ideas on how to silence the runtime error?

Comment: My understanding was that OP's original code works OK 'locally' and fails on heroku. Other than checking for versions mismatch I shared more details about where the message is coming from. Perhaps by doing a redundant fitting OP might reveal more details about the issue - even if that can be something silly like - "ok, I added one line to my original code and error should now originate from `previous_line_number + 1` but I am still getting the same message, same line number,... Is heroku actually picking up my updates?"